# Basic Plotting in "Modeling Techniques in Predictive Analytics"

Tags: r, plot, analytics

I am trying to plot the x and y pairs as demonstrated below. Can someone provide me with the basic code to plot x1, y1? I've tried a number of things to include plot(x1,y1) and its not recognizing these variables.

```
 # The Anscsombe Quartet in R

# demonstration data from
# Anscombe, F. J. 1973, February. Graphs in statistical analysis. 
#  The American Statistician 27: 17â21.

# define the anscombe data frame
anscombe <- data.frame(
   x1 = c(10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5),
   x2 = c(10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5),
   x3 = c(10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5),
   x4 = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 8, 8, 8),
   y1 = c(8.04, 6.95,  7.58, 8.81, 8.33, 9.96, 7.24, 4.26,10.84, 4.82, 5.68),
   y2 = c(9.14, 8.14,  8.74, 8.77, 9.26, 8.1, 6.13, 3.1,  9.13, 7.26, 4.74),
   y3 = c(7.46, 6.77, 12.74, 7.11, 7.81, 8.84, 6.08, 5.39, 8.15, 6.42, 5.73),
   y4 = c(6.58, 5.76,  7.71, 8.84, 8.47, 7.04, 5.25, 12.5, 5.56, 7.91, 6.89))

# show results from four regression analyses
with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y1 ~ x1))))
with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y2 ~ x2))))
with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y3 ~ x3))))
with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y4 ~ x4))))

# place four plots on one page using standard R graphics
# ensuring that all have the same scales
# for horizontal and vertical axes
pdf(file = "fig_more_anscombe.pdf", width = 8.5, height = 8.5)
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(3,3,3,1))
with(anscombe, plot(x1, y1, xlim=c(2,20),ylim=c(2,14), 
  pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 2, las = 1)
title("Set I")
with(anscombe,plot(x2, y2, xlim=c(2,20),ylim=c(2,14), 
  pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 2, las = 1))
title("Set II")
with(anscombe,plot(x3, y3, xlim=c(2,20),ylim=c(2,14), 
  pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 2, las = 1))
title("Set III")
with(anscombe,plot(x4, y4, xlim=c(2,20),ylim=c(2,14), 
  pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 2, las = 1))
title("Set IV")
dev.off()

par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))  # return to plotting defaults

# suggestions for the student
# see if you can develop a quartet of your own 
# or perhaps just a duet... 
# two very different data sets with the same fitted model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `anscombe` data set comes with R out of the box and does not have to be defined.

The code below sets up a 2x2 grid for plotting and then calculates the overall range for the x and separately for the y variables.   Then for i = 1, 2, 3, 4 it creates the ith formula and plots it using the calculated ranges.  `as.roman` is used to get the roman numeral portion of the title.  Then we perform a linear regression.  We could have just written `fm <- lm(fo, anscombe)` to calculate the regression but had we done that, the `print(summary(fm))` output would have shown literally `fo` as the formula which is not very nice.  Finally we plot the regression line using `abline` and print the summary.

Try this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

xrange <- range(anscombe[1:4])
yrange <- range(anscombe[5:8])

for(i in 1:4) {
  fo <- as.formula( sprintf("y%d ~ x%d", i, i) )
  plot(fo, anscombe, xlim = xrange, ylim = yrange, main = paste("Set", as.roman(i)))
  fm <- do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(anscombe)))
  abline(fm)
  print( summary(fm) )
}

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

giving this plot (output from `print(summary(...))` not shown):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I create a new script with everything from the beginning to the end of with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y4 ~ x4)))) and applied your code and am not receiving any plots still.

Comment: Start a fresh R session and paste the code shown into it without making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is plot x1 and y1, try:

```
plot(anscombe$x1,anscombe$y1)
```

or (from your code):

```
with(anscombe, plot(x1, y1, xlim=c(2,20),ylim=c(2,14), 
  pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 2, las = 1)
```

Your above code is plotting them to a pdf file, starting at the line:

```
pdf(file = "fig_more_anscombe.pdf", width = 8.5, height = 8.5)
```

and not ending until you terminate the pdf at:

```
dev.off()
```

If you don't terminate the pdf, you will never see a plot output in R. If you have run the code multiple times, make sure no pdf devices are open by running:

```
dev.off()
```

until you see:

```
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info on dev.off() and the creating a pdf.. However, I take all the top code up till with(anscombe, print(summary(lm(y4 ~ x4)))) and try plotting via plot(anscombe$x1,anscombe$y1) and am not getting any plots still.